# How to filter lowest date of month from a list in excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a list of daily values for several years in excel. It shows values for a stock price index and therefore doesn't always start at the first day of month but rather the first weekday of the month, when markets open.

How can I quickly filter out a list that shows only the first logged day of each month? I.e. 1., 2., or 3rd?

Thank you!

Comment: Is the data in order by date ?

Comment: Yes, It's in order. dd.mm.yyyy from 01.01.1993 untill 08.03.2016 giving a total of  5.775 entries. 

Ideally I need a list with only the values corresponding to first day of each month as that would enable me to copy and paste the list to a master list that I am working with that has the same (first day of month) format and not the other circa 30 days.

Comment: Just to clarify, the task doesn't require figuring out what the first date should be for each month, it's just selecting the entry with the earliest date in each month?

Answer (score 1):

Well, assuming the data is in chronological order by date ...

you can setup conditional formatting to highlight the first item of each month by using something like this:

```
=IF(ISERROR(MONTH($A1)),TRUE,MONTH($A2)<>MONTH($A1))
```

This formula assumes your data is in cells A2 and below and has a header on row 1. Select all the rows, (with Cell A2 being the main selected one) and create a new conditional format, using the above formula.

The funky logic is to avoid it tripping over the header for the first row.
If you have no header, and your data starts in Cell A1 .. do this:

1) highlight row 1 (it'll always be the first ...)

2) highlight cells A2 and below ... and just use this formula:

```
=MONTH(A2)<>MONTH(A1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a helper column First Weekday where you write the Formula before your Filter. The Formula calculate the First weekday of the month and write First in the helper column
=IF(A2=Eomonth(A2,-1)+1+Choose(Weedkday(Eomonth(A2,-1)+1,2),0,0,0,0,0,2,1),"First","")
A2 is the date in your table, then Filter First Weekday column = First

Answer (score 0):

I just had a similar problem where I had to find the first entry for each month. This is how I was able to do it.

1. Sort data in chronological order.
2. Assume the first date starts on A2. On B2, insert this formula:

=text(A2,"mmm/yyyy")

This will give a result of, say, Jan/2012.

3. Copy the above formula all the way down to cover all the dates in your log.
4. In C2, type this formula:

=if(B2=B1,"No","Yes")

5. Copy the above formula all the way down.

This will return a "yes" every time a new month starts. Simply filter for "yes" and you will have what you need.

Fairly simple once you think about it. :]

Answer (score -1):

To organize your dates into earliest date to oldest, select all the numbers (dates), then go to Data tab> Sort and filter group, then click [image: Smallest to largest](Smallest to Largest)

https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Sort-data-in-a-range-or-table-62d0b95d-2a90-4610-a6ae-2e545c4a4654#bmsort_numbers

Comment: That's not what the OP is asking for.

Comment: Oh, I don't understand it very well. I though this would help because it would allow him to see the earliest date for each month.